# left join not working - get records not in other table

Tags: mysql, join

I feel weird, as every other answer says it works, but I can't get the correct results :(

```
table A: id_num, name<br>
table B: id_num

table A has index on name, but not unique. id_num is unique in this table.<br>
table B has index on id_num, but not unique.
```

I want to get table A names, who are NOT in table B.

This not working:

```
**SELECT a.name FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.id_num = b.id_num) 
WHERE b.id_numb IS NULL**
```

its returning names that ARE in table b (and some that are not).

this didn't work either:

```
**SELECT distinct(a.name) 
FROM a where a.id_num 
not in (select distinct(b.id_num) from b  )**
```

I can't comprehend how a.names are being return who ARE IN table B, when the SQL says NOT IN.
what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: can you post some data for each table?

Comment: column name, some data and the result you want to get.

Comment: is the `WHERE b.id_numb` typo only on SO, or in your actual code?

Comment: Start simpler to understand what your query is doing. First run something like: SELECT a.id_num, a.name, b.id_num FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.id_num = b.id_num) ** see if this result looks like you think it should, then add your where clause. Also, the previous comment by Benjam.

Comment: @user1864734 I just posted the following as a reference and a sample for you to comment. So everyone here can understand your issue. So **it's not a direct answer to your question**.

Comment: that sqlfiddle thing is the COOLEST thing I've seen in a long time!!! that is just awesome. Thanks for sharing. I'm tweaking the data to fit my issue.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/987c3/2/0  --- how to make rose, only appear in the results?

Comment: THIS was the answer: select t1.col2 from tab1 t1
     where t1.col2 not in 
               (select t3.col2 from tab1 t3, tab2 t2 where t2.col4 = t3.col1 );

Answer (score 0):

By right, the `left join` should work. And as well as `in`.

Here is a sample. So you may want to publish and show your table schema and data for more justice on your question. Best if you could just create the tables on SQLFIDDLE and show the reference. ;)

Here is just **SAMPLE**:-

- [SQLFIDDLE reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d55/1)

Sample Tables:
tab1:

```
   COL1     COL2
    1       john
    2       tim
    3       jack
    4       rose
```

tab2:

```
   COL3     COL4
    1       2
    2       3
    3       5
    4       5
    5       2
```

Query:

```
select * from tab1
where col1 not in 
(select distinct col4 from tab2)
;
```

Results:

```
COL1    COL2
1       john
4       rose
```

---

### As per OP's updated comments and table structure

- OP mentioned the table tab1 will have multiple records for same name. According to his original table design, there's **NO NAME** field in the table tab2. It's also much recommended if OP had provided the expected results initially.

### * [SQLFIDDLE Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a324/3)

OP's table data:

```
COL1    COL2
1       john
2       tim
3       jack
4       rose
5       john
6       john

COL3    COL4
1       2
2       3
3       5
4       5
5       2
6       6
```

Query: **When you do not want any name that is duplicated**

```
select t.col1, t.col2
from tab1 t
join 
 (select t1.col2, count(*) as counts 
  from tab1 t1
  group by t1.col2
  having count(*) = 1) x
on t.col2 = x.col2
where t.col1 not in 
 (select distinct col4 from tab2)
;
```

Results: **Here is Rose, the only record that has no duplicates and do not exist in tab2**

```
COL1    COL2
4       rose
```

Comment: okay... so the query I had in the original problem is working, just like this one.  I've realized the data results is correct, but I just now figured out what the problem is.  REASON:  in the above tab1, say there is multiple john records (5, john and 6, john) AND in tab2 you add only one of those john records (6,6) => john no longer appears in the results, but I know 2 john records don't exist in tab2.  I'm missed the 3rd record. I was ONLY looking at the "name", not the id and the name. So not sure how to get the results I'm looking for. Which is for NO names to be in tab2.

Comment: I tried this, but no different results:  **select distinct(col2) from tab1
where tab1.col1 not in (select distinct(col3) from tab2) group by col2**

Comment: @user1864734 the query also depends on the way you design your table schema and relations :) If you had mentioned for e.g. that you have multiple Johns, then we would have surely showed a query to support that. My answer was for you to get a heads up. These tables are normalized. When you have multiple Johns, it's recommended to put proper primary keys - **perhaps a compound key.** Check out the updated version. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select t1.name from table1 t1
     where t1.name not in 
               (select t2.name from table2 t2 )
```

look the  [**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8d5e/1)

**EDIT:**

if you have only `id_num` in your second table then here look to

[**THIS DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1539/11)

Comment: THANKS... because you put the "name not in"... it made me think of the solution!!

Comment: @goodmood according to your solution, OP must change his `table2` by adding a `name` column. In his original table schema, there's only `id`.. ;)

Comment: @user1864734 look my edited answer . and if it helps you make sure to accept the answer .